# How to run ROS command from a python script?

Tags: ros, python, shell

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I need some help as I was trying to write a python script which could run some ROS commands, such as $rostopic list and $rostopic echo(while some nodes are running). I tried something like the following, but none of them works.
when I tried this:

```
os.system("rostopic list")
```

I got this error when I ran the above: sh: 1: rostopic: not found

Or this:

```
subprocess.call(["rostopic", "list"])
```

It was not working and a error message was given like this "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'rostopic'"

I was thinking about execute a shell script from my python script, but I don't know how to write one for running ROS commands.

I appreciate any help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262770/how-to-run-ros-command-from-a-python-script?/) by [Radar](https://answers.ros.org/users/30551/radar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-05-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can get the topics much easier using the rospy client functions [rospy client module](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/rospy/html/rospy.client-module.html)

```
import rospy
l = rospy.get_published_topics()
```

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2017-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would do what @NEngelhard suggests, but just to answer your question: you need to run your Python script in an environment that has been setup with the ROS environment variables.

Two ways to do that:

- start your script from a terminal in which you've `source`d the right `setup.bash`
- setup the environment which is created by `os.system(..)` with the needed environment variables

If you do want to continue starting ROS command line utilities, I'd recommend you use `subprocess` or `popen` instead of `os.system(..)`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1